# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'functional'

Tags: python, python-3.x, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to recur the papper [dressing-in-order](https://github.com/cuiaiyu/dressing-in-order) ,but i am facing with this error:"AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'functional'"

I just installed pytorch 1.10.1 ,Python 3.6.2 for windows 11.

```
import torch
from models.dior_model import DIORModel
import os, json
import torch.nn.functional as F
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
```

**error as follow:**

```
AttributeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-8f34f6d79efa> in <module>()
  1 import torch
 ----> 2 from models.dior_model import DIORModel
  3 import os, json
  4 import torch.nn.functional as F
  5 from PIL import Image

~\Desktop\DiOr复现\dressing-in-order-main\models\__init__.py in <module>()
 17 
 18 import importlib
---> 19 from models.base_model import BaseModel
 20 
 21 

~\Desktop\DiOr复现\dressing-in-order-main\models\base_model.py in <module>()
  3 from collections import OrderedDict
  4 from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
----> 5 from . import networks
  6 from tensorboardX import SummaryWriter
  7 import shutil

~\Desktop\DiOr复现\dressing-in-order-main\models\networks\__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from .base_networks import *
  2 from .generators import *
  3 from .vgg import *
  4 from .gfla import PoseFlowNet, ResDiscriminator
  5 import importlib

~\Desktop\DiOr复现\dressing-in-order-main\models\networks\base_networks.py in <module>()
  6 import functools
  7 import torch
 ----> 8 import torch.nn.functional as F
  9 from torch.autograd import Variable
 10 import math

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'functional'
```

Comment: It looks like one of the earlier imports (most likely `from models.dior_model import DIORModel`) redefined `torch` as a global object that has an integer attribute called `nn`.

Comment: Is there more code above `import torch.nn.functional as F`? Most likely is what Grismar said